# Reusing json/model object to avoid making extra calls to controller

Tags: grails, dojo

I've got a groovy userController and a _listMyUsers.gsp.
The _listMyUsers.gsp is using a

```
 <g:dojoRemoteForm
            formName="userSearchForm"
            id="userSearchForm"
            url="[controller:'user',action:'search']"
            update="[success:'content']">
```

The method in the userController (search) is a simple criteria builder which returns the following back to the gsp, You can use controls in the gsp to customize the search criteria parameters (passed to the controller as param.field_name):

```
    render (template:"listUsers",
            model:[
                    users:users,
                    userTypes:UserTypeLookup.list(),
                    sortby:params.sortby,
                    direction:nextDirection,
                    currentDirection:sortDirection,
                    pager:pager,
                    organizations:orgs,
                    userType:userSearchTypes
            ])
```

Now this all works great and the model is then used to build out my usersList table.  My problem comes in when I click on one of the users in the results to edit said users data, I then save.  The save completes and returns to the main listUsers table.  But it re-runs the search method with all searchCriteria wild carded as 'ALL' in the selections (so all users in the DB are returned).
My question is, how can I preserve the initial "custom" search returned so that when I get done editing my user, the original "search" is still there so my UI users don't have to go back and re-do their userSearch criteria again?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The [Grails Cache Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/cache) might help you here. You could cache the output form the `search` action, using the user's query parameters as method arguments (so they can be used as keys to the cache).

```
@Cacheable('searchResults')
def search(String sortBy, String sortDirection /* other parameters */)   {
  // render the output
}
```

Then in your save action, you can use the `CacheEvict` annotation to clear the `searchResults` cache, so the `search` action will return the latest data:

```
@CacheEvict(value='searchResults', allEntries=true)
def saveUser() {
  //save the user and return a response code
}
```

See the [plugin documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/guide/usage.html) for details on specifying which items in the cache to evict, etc.